# Sending form with a new value that i got from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

My problem is the next one:

I have a form that leads me to another webpage, so i have to go to that web with parameters set by the form.

Its something like

```
<form action="www.foo.com/">
<input type="text" value="0" name="test"/>
<input type="text" value="" name="promo_code"/>
</form>
```

I have a button to submit that form
When i click on this button, i get from an ajax call a new value for the input test depending on what i set on the promo_code input. So after the ajax call the form looks like this

```
  <form action="www.foo.com/">
    <input type="text" value="foobar" name="test"/>
    <input type="text" value="bar" name="promo_code"/>
    </form>
```

My problem is that when i submit the form after the ajax call, the parameters that are being send are this `.../?test="0"&promo_code="bar"` instead of `.../?test="foobar"&promo_code="bar"`

The parameters are updated if i click the button for submiting the form a second time.

What can i do for solving this problem?

Comment: you sure this is your code? seems like you are using number type for input

Comment: Also, post your javascript/jquery

Comment: please post all the relevant code, e.g. how you trigger the ajax request, the ajax request itself, and how you update the form after that, and also how you submit the form. We have only got access to part of the puzzle.